# Will Windows 8 Release Preview support Bing Maps?

Tags: windows-8, bing-maps

I experienced an error while running the Bing Maps sample. I am trying to add Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Package in references, but I couldn't find it. Will Windows 8 Release Preview support Bing Maps?

Comment: could not find microsoft.vclibs version=11.0 error .

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2012/03/06/bing-maps-for-winrt-xaml.aspx) blog post, either you don't have the Visual C++ runtime package installed or, if you have marked the check-box in the reference manager and are experiencing a set of errors (as indicated in the blog), you may have to change your target architecture--amd or x86.

There are step-by-step instructions on how to add Bing maps to your application in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh855146.aspx) provided by Microsoft.

Comment: i saw the document my SDK does not have Visual C++ runtime package to add it to my solution.where to download that dll.

Comment: @user1645335 do you have both Win8 RTM and visual studio 2012? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/br229516